# Spring Boot application is not able to detect the file present in classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have given below in application.yml file in spring boot application

`file.path: classpath:input.txt`

I have placed input.txt under src/main/resources

When i deploy the application in docker, getting below exception

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [input.txt] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/input.txt`

But when I run it from local, file is getting loaded. Please suggest a way to fix it.

Comment: Show the code about how you are reading the file.

Comment: @Value("${file.path}") private String filepath;  and in method accessing file using File f = new File(filepath);

Comment: Seems you trying to make input.txt as part of jar and when running the jar it should resolve from inside it. Can you please check if input.txt available inside the jar under BOOT-INF/classes? It will be better if you can keep input.txt outside of jar and put that folder on class path.

Comment: You can not use like this.

Comment: @AshokPrajapati, in our project we are not managing dockers, we will pass our jar to team and they will deploy. So file should be part of our jar. And i can see file is present under BOOT-INF/classes. I can able to test the application from command prompt. When it deployed in docker, facing this issue

Comment: Did someone has any luck with how to solve this? I am facing the same exception of YAML file in BOOT-INF/classes but doesn't get picked up with `classpath:fileName.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer I noticed you're loading the file like this:

```java
@Value("${file.path}") //classpath:input.txt
private String filePath;

private void readFile() {
    new File(filePath);
}
```

To make it work you can use it like this:

```java
@Value("${file.path}")
private org.springframework.core.io.Resource file;

private void readFile() {
   InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
   // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the file using the following code in Spring.

```
File rese = new ClassPathResource("input.txt").getFile();
String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(res.toPath()));
```